# Update a column using two variables

Tags: sql-server

My code is

```
DECLARE @nextYear Integer = 0;
select @nextYear = DATEPART(yy,getdate())+1

DECLARE @nextMonth DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @mon integer = 0;
SELECT @mon = MONTH(EOMONTH ( @nextMonth, 1 )) 

update Mytable set
month_of_usage = '@mon/@nextYear' where id = 1
```

Data type of month_of_usage is varchar.
I need month of usage to be set as 11/2021. This script is meant to automatically populate data for next month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
update Mytable set
month_of_usage = Cast(@mon as varchar(10)) + '/' + Cast(@nextYear as Varchar(10)) where id = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

`'@mon/@nextYear'` would mean the **literal** string value `'@mon/@nextYear'`; *not* the value of `@mon` followed by `/` followed by the value of `@nextYear`.

You need to concatenate the values:

```sql
UPDATE MyTable
SET month_of_usage = CONCAT(RIGHT(CONCAT('00',@mon),2),'/',@nextYear)
WHERE id = 1;
```

I  also use `RIGHT` to create a value that always have the same format, `MM/yyyy`, as otherwise you would get values like `'1/2020'` and `'10/2020'`.

Of course, that looks like it's attempting to represent a date, and a `varchar` is the completely wrong data type for that. For example, according to your data, `01/2020` is **before** `12/1999`. If you need to store date related data, use a Date and Time Data type; there are 6 to choose from and at least one of them will be appropriate.